# How to add two add_custom_command commands to execute one by one

Tags: cmake

I have a script

```
list(LENGTH SRC_FBS_FILES LEN)
math(EXPR FBS_LIST_NUM "${LEN} - 1")
foreach (LIST_ITEM RANGE ${FBS_LIST_NUM})
    list(GET SRC_FBS_FILES ${LIST_ITEM} SRC_FBS_FILE)
    list(GET DST_FBS_FILES ${LIST_ITEM} DST_FBS_FILE)
    list(GET GEN_FBS_FILES ${LIST_ITEM} GEN_FBS_FILE)

    get_filename_component(DST_FBS_FILE_DIR ${DST_FBS_FILE} DIRECTORY)

    add_custom_command (OUTPUT "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${GEN_FBS_FILE}"
            COMMENT "Generating flatbuffers header ${GEN_FBS_FILE} from ${SRC_FBS_FILE}"
            COMMAND ${_FLATC} --cpp "${SRC_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${SRC_FBS_FILE}"
            WORKING_DIRECTORY "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}"
            DEPENDS "${SRC_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${SRC_FBS_FILE}"
            )

    add_custom_command(
            OUTPUT "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${DST_FBS_FILE}"
            COMMENT "Renaming '${GEN_FBS_FILE}' to '${DST_FBS_FILE}'"
            #${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E echo "ETest"
            COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy
            "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${GEN_FBS_FILE}"
            "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${DST_FBS_FILE}"
            DEPENDS "${SRC_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${GEN_FBS_FILE}"
            )

    set(FLATBUFFERS_H_FILES ${FLATBUFFERS_H_FILES} "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${GEN_FBS_FILE}")
endforeach()
```

I want to rename output files from flatbuffer utility. But second script never runs, cmake event doesn't tell anything about it's syntax of result.

I understand that it is significant to use OUTPUT result somewhere, and if I, for example, change

```
    set(FLATBUFFERS_H_FILES ${FLATBUFFERS_H_FILES} "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${GEN_FBS_FILE}")
```

to

```
    set(FLATBUFFERS_H_FILES ${FLATBUFFERS_H_FILES} "${DST_FLATBUFFERS_DIR}/${DST_FBS_FILE}")
```

I changed "GEN..." to "DST..." then even by first "add_custom_command" never runs.

So what is the logic to append one command after another and guarantee them both to execute?

Comment: sooo `add_custom_command( COMMAND cmd1 COMMAND cmd2 ...)`

Comment: It works, thanks. What can I do with this question? I can't resolve it with your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify command multiple times in `add_custom_command`.

```
add_custom_command(
      COMMAND cmd1 arg11 arg12
      COMMAND cmd2 arg21 arg22
      ..etc...
)
```

It is guaranteed that the commands will execute in order.